# Bootstrap in a frameset issue with iOS browsers

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, frameset, scorm

http://www.learningservices.us/sample (with frames)
http://www.learningservices.us/sample/page1.htm (without frames)

The site I'm developing must use a frameset.  It is there to maintain the communication with a SCORM compliant learning management system (LMS) API.

The sample page without the frameset looks and acts perfectly (though still under development).  However, once inside the frameset, the sticky/always visible footer doesn't act the same way.

I have the viewport metatag in both the parent frameset page, and the child page (page1.htm), but it still doesn't behave.

Comment: Does the LMS support Tin Can API http://tincanapi.com ? If you could use that instead of SCORM, you could do away with frames.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Government client with older LMS.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've come up with a way to handle all of this gracefully.  First, I launch the SCO like normal, but instead of loading the content pages (done in Bootstrap) in the main frame of the SCORM frameset, I simply load a page that in turn launches a new window without a frameset with the content pages.  And now instead of referencing the parent frame as parent.value, I now reference opener.parent.value.  The SCORM calls work, page navigation works like always, everything just works and no framesets to mess me up.  So now when I'm done with the launched window, I also close the SCORM frameset window too and the learner is returned to the LMS with his/her desktop clean.

Once everything is completely polished, I'll post a sample.

Comment: Yeah framesets are tricky on mobile.  They tend to hurt performance a bit, then become a little more fun to manage.  Opening a new tab / window is fine, except that if you have a memory heavy activity it can actually unload your LMS tab or refresh it when you exit the SCO.  Least in my tests the SCORM Runtime still responds, but sometimes the student has to re-login.  I typically load up SCO Pages via AJAX now vs using yet another frame.